# Module is an object or a class?

Tags: chisel

In chisel, we should always extend from 'Module' to define our own module, right?

But, I can only find the definition of 'Module' at 'core/src/main/scala/chisel3/Module.scala' - it's a 'object'! We extend from an object? Or sth I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend Module the class hierarchy looks like
`Module` <= `abstract class LegacyModule`. So it is a class. There is also a `object Module` that has `apply` methods that are used differently. BTW, having a good IDE like IntelliJ can make it much easier to navigate class hierarchies and figure out where things are coming from.

Comment: Think you, there's a type alias...
'type Module = chisel3.internal.LegacyModule' in 'core/src/main/scala/chisel3/package.scala'